# colorcoding tableview cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im trying to colorcode my tableview based on a property `partySize` that belongs to each member of a `mutableArray` thats the data source for my tableview. I want to do this in `willDisplayCell` and NOT `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when I have the code as it, nothing happens, all the cells are white. The middle column is where the `partySize` data is listed.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    QueueMember *member = (self.queue)[indexPath.row];
    switch (member.partySize) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            break;
        case 3:
        case 4:
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        case 5:
        case 6:
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        case 7:
        case 8:
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        case 9:
        case 10:
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        default:
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
            break;
    }
}
```

I have looked it up on stack overflow already and know that there are ways to do this in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath but Id rather do this here because that's what apple's developer class reference for 'uitableviewcell' says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Add `break` s to your switch

```
switch (member.partySize) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            break;
        case 3:
        case 4:
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            break;
        case 5:
        case 6:
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            break;
        case 7:
        case 8:
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            break;
        case 9:
        case 10:
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            break;
        default:
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
            break;
    }
```

2.Try to change `cell.backgroundColor` to `cell.contentView.backgroundColor` everywhere.

Comment: thanks! this worked. however, my view has a disclosure indicator next to each cell on the right and this remains clear. any way to make this equal to the cell it's in?

Comment: Try to change `cell.accessoryView.color`. Please accept my answer if it helped you..

Comment: adding cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor into the switch has no effect on the color of the disclosure indicator.

Comment: I am sorry. I can not help you here.  I think you should create new question for this.